# Как скрыть блоки jquery

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как на jquery скрыть блоки c id_число

Comment: где n может быть любым числом

Answer (score 2):

```
var n = 5; // число
$("#block_" + n).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Z8S/

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать двумя путями:

1. В CSS есть селектор, позволяющий выделить элементы, аттрибуты которых начинаются с определённого значения. Но он сможет работать только если вы будете отделять цифры не подчёркиванием, а дефисом (какая-то фишка из спецификации CSS, почему так я не вникал). [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ydP2J/).
2. Существует [плагин](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) для jQuery, позволяющий искать по регулярным выражениям. С его помощью вы сможете добиться в точности того, что вам нужно. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ydP2J/2/).

Comment: Поправлю Вас и заодно объясню как работает ваш пример из первого пункта :)
Если вы поставите условие правильно, можно использовать как нижнее подчеркивание, так и тире, а можно вообще не использовать ни то, ни другое. Правильным в данном случае будет условие [class^="id"]. Дело в том, что символ ^ позволяет спозиционировать регулярное выражение относительно начала текста. Так же можно задать позицию с конца строки (читайте про регулярные выражения на википедии, раздел "Позиция внутри строки").

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/wanchucha/drkYz/